# Issuse with tab names in vb.net browser

Tags: vb.net

Well, i am creating a web browser in **VB.NET**... I know its stupid, but its true. My code is this:

```
        Dim tab As New TabPage
        Dim brws As New WebBrowser

        Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
        tab.Controls.Add(brws)
        brws.Navigate("google.com")
        tab.Text = brws.DocumentTitle
        brws.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab
```

and as well i take a look at the C# question, but that didn't hel me. Also, the code is in `try`.
My problem is that when i open [Google](http://google.com) the *title* don't appear. 
Line of the code:
`tab.Text = brws.DocumentTitle`
What's happening:
[Image on Bulgarian images hosting](http://www.prikachi.com/images.php?images/612/8966612A.png)
Also, please provide a code :) Thanks!
Dimitar

Comment: Cheers and welcome to Stackoverflow! This seems to be a fine question :) Notice however the usual place for uploading images is most likely [Imgur](http://imgur.com) here. You should probably not directly ask for others to provide code for you... Such direct request might be misunderstood by the one or the other.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Well, thanks! I forgot about imgur.. sorry. And thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: my guess is that `.DocumentTitle` is blank because the page did not complete loading. You can check with the debugger.

Comment: You can't get the title until that part of the source code is downloaded and parsed. Utilize the [**DocumentCompleted event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AddHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka) can be used to subscribe to the [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event:

```
Dim tab As New TabPage, brws As New WebBrowser

AddHandler brws.DocumentCompleted, Sub() tab.Text = brws.DocumentTitle

Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
tab.Controls.Add(brws)
brws.Navigate("google.com")
brws.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say something like "You can use AddHandler to subscribe to the DocumentCompleted event", since AddHandler is actually only part of the solution?

Comment: Thanks SOO much! This help me alot!

Comment: @VisualVincent I think "AddHandler" describes it better and "subscribe" can make it a tiny bit more confusing, but I'll add it

Comment: `I think "AddHandler" describes it better` - But `AddHandler` can be used in many different situations and is only part of the solution. After all it is _which_ event you subscribe to that matters. :) -- `"subscribe" can make it a tiny bit more confusing` - I'm interested to know what you think can be confusing about it. IMO "subscribing to an event" is not confusing at all.

Comment: @VisualVincent might be just my different experience and way of thinking because to me, subscribe doesn't seem like the best word to describe it. From what I notice, it seems to be used more in C# related articles, but I don't see it in VB related articles. To me "to handle" feels a bit more natural, but that would be redundant and technically incorrect.

Comment: `subscribe doesn't seem like the best word to describe it` - Though you are being "notified" when an event is raised, so it works similar to when you subscribe to a newsletter, for example. -- `it seems to be used more in C# related articles` - Yes, though C# and VB.NET uses the same event system, just different syntaxes and VB.NET does some more underlying work with its events.

Comment: `To me "to handle" feels a bit more natural, but that would be redundant and technically incorrect.` - "To handle" is a good phrase, yes. Though I wouldn't say it's technically incorrect since you're handling what happens when an event occurs. -- You have interesting points. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!